# MySQL - wp index

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am not too familiar with MySQL. I've done some research on a problem I was having with my wpx table (which is 4GB - massive site) and it was doing a full table scan which was taking up a lot of resources.

I added a query to add an index and this solved my server problems.

ALTER TABLE wp_options ADD INDEX (`autoload`);

However, Google is having problems crawling my site and this has been the case since I've added this query. How do I simply remove this and remove the index?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please give more details? It sounds like you want to remove the index, but what else do you want to remove? How do you know that Google is having problems and how do you know your index is to blame?

Comment: How many rows does your wp_options table contain? It seems strange that adding that index would slow things down. Is the table you call `wpx` part of a standard WordPress instance? If so, it probably has some other name. Do you know what query in WordPress is doing the full table scan?

Comment: The index should not, *in any way* hamper Google crawling your site. Indeed if it has improved response times then it will improve Google's ability to crawl your site and your ranking.

What are your reasons for thinking this is the case?

Comment: Adding an index to your table to improve server performance influences Google's crawler indexing your site as much as me turning my light on and off. You went wrong somewhere with your logic here, sorting your server issues has nothing to do with google going through your site. Unless your site errored out while index was being made, if it errored out. So - time to check them server logs to see what went on.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the index use `DROP INDEX`.

```
DROP INDEX autoload on wp_options
```